# MATLAB- nested for loops

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to teach myself Matlab for the past few weeks. and I have questions regarding nested for loops in Matlab.

For example, I have to print out this pattern-

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Now, this pattern has a varying number of columns for an array. how do I write the code for this layout?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you tried this, and say what problem you are encountering?

Comment: @ViG I haven't tried anything yet, because I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops for this, one loop will do:

```
N = 5;

for ii=1:N
    str = num2str(1:ii);
    str = strsplit(str, ' ');
    disp(strcat(strjoin(str,''),strjoin(str(end-1:-1:1),'')));
end
```

explanation of different steps:

- `num2str(1:ii)` returns a string that contains the numbers of the
  array separated by a space.
- `strsplit(str, ' ')` returns an cell array where each cell contains a
  string.
- `strcat(strjoin(str,'')` concatenates all the strings together (no
  space inbetween so this is actually the `num2str(1:ii)` without
  spaces)
- `strjoin(str(end-1:-1:1),''))` does the same, but the cells are
  adressed in reverse order, and the last one is omitted.

output:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Answer (score 0):

If your task just involves the production of strings, the answer of @ViG should perfectly fit your needs. On the opposite side, if you must produce real numbers and display them, this one liner can accomplish it:

```
N = 5;

for i=1:N
    disp(num2str(sum([sum((i:-1:1).*(repmat(10,1,i).^((i-1):-1:0))) sum((1:(i-1)).*10^(i-1).*(repmat(10,1,i-1).^((i-1):-1:1)))])));
end
```

The final output is, of course:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Let's break it down for the sake of being clear:

```
N = 5;

for i=1:N
    % Build the lower part of the number (for i=5, it is 54321)...
    lo = sum((i:-1:1) .* (repmat(10,1,i) .^ ((i-1):-1:0)));

    % Build the upper part of the number (for i=5, it is 123400000)...
    hi = sum((1:(i-1)) .* 10^(i-1) .* (repmat(10,1,i-1) .^ ((i-1):-1:1)));

    % Build the final result by summing the upper and lower parts together...
    res = sum([lo hi]);

    % Display the final result (num2str helps outputting a pretty formatted strings)...
    disp(num2str(res));
end
```

Let's break it down even more:

```
N = 5;

for i=1:N
    % Build a sequence for the lower part (for i=5, it is [5 4 3 2 1])...
    lo_seq = i:-1:1;
    % Build a sequence of 10^X for the lower part (for i=5, it is [10000 1000 100 10 1])...
    lo_mul = repmat(10,1,i) .^ ((i-1):-1:0);
    % Obtain the lower part by summing the above sequences multiplied together...
    lo = sum(lo_seq .* lo_mul);

    % Build a sequence for the upper part (for i=5, it is [1 2 3 4])...
    hi_seq = 1:(i-1);
    % Build a sequence of 10^X for the upper part (for i=5, it is [10000 1000 100 10])...
    hi_mul = repmat(10,1,i-1) .^ ((i-1):-1:1);
    % Create a coefficient for scaling up the above sequences (for i=5, it is 10000)...
    hi_coe = 10^(i-1);
    % Obtain the lower part by summing the above sequences multiplied together and with the coefficient...
    hi = sum(hi_seq .* hi_coe .* hi_mul);

    % Build the final result by summing the upper and lower parts together...
    res = sum([lo hi]);

    % Display the final result (num2str helps outputting a pretty formatted strings)...
    disp(num2str(res));
end
```

The code above can be also improved a little:

```
N = 5;

for i=1:N
    lo_seq = i:-1:1;
    lo_mul = repmat(10,1,i) .^ ((i-1):-1:0);
    lo = sum(lo_seq .* lo_mul);

    hi_seq = fliplr(lo_seq(2:end));
    hi_mul = lo_mul(1:end-1);
    hi = 10^(i-1) * sum(hi_seq .* hi_mul);

    res = sum([lo hi]);
    disp(num2str(res));
end
```

Comment: Because you're dealing with numbers, this won't work for `N > 9`.